# Determine the Taylor expansion of a function at a certain point of order n.

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Trying to determine the taylor expansion of  $\frac{1}{x+1} $ at 0 of order 2000 any hint please?

Comment: geometric series?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most known geometric series states that for $|x|<1$ :

$$\frac{1}{x+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n$$

Recall that the Taylor expansion of a function $f$ at a point $a$ is given as :

$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3 + \dots$$

I guess by order, you mean either the rank/order of the "highest" power in the expression or of the derivative present, so guessing you'll want to go until the $2000th$ power of $x$ **or** derivative, you would need the "first" $2001$ terms of the infinite series above, which means you want :

$$\sum_{n=0}^{2001}(-1)^nx^n$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{1}{1-(-x)} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-x)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k x^k$$

That is:

$$1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5 + x^6 - x^7 + x^8 - x^9 + ...$$